# How can i enable VFP or NEON support in my C++ Android appolication?

Tags: gcc, android-ndk

By default Android NDK does not generate code with VFP (vector floating point) or NEON instructions turned on. How can i turn them on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are documentation about this in the following files in Android NDK: docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html and docs/CPU-ARM-NEON.html.

Basically you want to put

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

to generate two shared libraries, one without (targeting ARMv5TE) and one with VFP support (targeting ARMv7).

To build .c/.cpp file with NEON support add .neon suffix to filename (for example: file.cpp.neon) in Android.mk file. Or to build all files with NEON enabled, put into Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
```

Be careful - not all ARMv7 devices support NEON (like Nvidia Tegra 2). Better detect it at runtime and choose different codepath then.

Read the docs for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to put 2 binaries into the .apk (armv7 and neon) so that the system can select the correct one automatically?

Comment: Yes, it is done automatically (for armeabi and armeabi-v7a, and now x86). Read the docs - section "III.1. Native code in Application Packages"